# Matrix from File

Tags: java

I am trying to create a matrix from a text file. The problem is that when the Buffered Reader function readline() is done parsing first line of file it comes to second line but the its reading it as empty which it is not.

```
void covar()
    {
        double [][]covar=new double[10][5];
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("class 1\\feature_vector.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String input;

            while((input=br.readLine())!= null)
            {               
                String [] temp=input.split(",");
                //System.out.println(input.split(",").length);
                covar[i][j]= new Double(temp[0]);
                covar[i+1][j]=new Double(temp[1]);
                covar[i+2][j]=new Double(temp[2]);
                covar[i+3][j]=new Double(temp[3]);
                covar[i+4][j]=new Double(temp[4]);
                //i=0;
                j++;
            }

            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Above is the code. The file name is perfect and nothing is wrong with the stream thing. Can you guys help me out with what is wrong with this.

Here is the content of the file:

```
0.75,321.0,0.22429906,0.97507787,1.966202512778112
0.33333334,135.0,-0.014814815,1.0,5.323770568766052
0.64285713,311.0,0.025723472,1.0,4.764298570227433
0.6,188.0,0.03723404,1.0,4.7349608150168105
0.25,189.0,0.16931216,0.98941797,7.15681209803803
0.71428573,194.0,-0.26804122,0.96391755,5.1654456838422425
0.6,173.0,0.028901733,1.0,6.54275787030257
0.2857143,257.0,0.031128405,1.0,6.095356508899233
0.23076923,197.0,-0.04568528,1.0,3.784908227189768
0.18181819,231.0,0.17316018,0.987013,5.956322938602553
```

Comment: i had earlier thought the I should force i to 0 & then realized that it is not necessary as per my requirements so I put it in comments.

Comment: This has nothing to do with problem, but : that DataInputStream is totally unnecessary, remove it.

Comment: if I delete DataInputStream then how am I going to get data stream from the file?

Comment: Straight from the FileInputStream

Comment: Meaning `BufferedInputStream( fstream )`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that are obviously wrong:

- You do not need variable `i`, because one of the dimensions is fixed, and you "unrolled" the loop five times
- You swapped the indexes: `j` should go first, that's the one changing from `0` to `9`.

For example:

```
String [] temp=input.split(",");
covar[j][0] = new Double(temp[0]);
covar[j][1] =new Double(temp[1]);
covar[j][2] =new Double(temp[2]);
covar[j][3] =new Double(temp[3]);
covar[j][4] =new Double(temp[4]);
```

You could put the loop back to shorten your code:

```
String [] temp=input.split(",");
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    covar[j][i] = new Double(temp[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What I am trying to do is to get the data from a file that has data in format like 1st line(  1,2,3,4,5) 2nd line( 6,7,8,9,10)  Now i need to add this data to a matrix in same order of size 2X5. I was trying to do it as stated above but clearly am missing something. Please enlighten.  Thanks again

Comment: @user1347525 Then your matrix should be `[2][5]`.

Comment: @user1347525 When you modify your code to fit the above, do you get errors? Do items come in the wrong order? Please be more specific about the errors that you see.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight: The problem is not with the sequence of data inserted into the matrix the problem is with "input=br.readLine()" this part. For the first line of the file input has the whole line read and the code in while loop runs fine. Now when the loop runs for the second line somehow input ="" hence the code in between while loop doesn't run.

Comment: @user1347525 Could you edit the question to add the content of your file? Indent it with four spaces to make it easier to read.

Comment: @user1347525 Check if your file has correct line breaks. Put back that `println` for the number of tokens that you get, print individual tokens, and so on.

Comment: I cant understand what is wrong with this thing. I swapped the contents of the file with more simple data format i.e 1,2,3,4 and so on; now the code runs just fine but as soon as I switch to the original content it shows an error. It is just a file reading how is data format effecting the outcome?

Comment: @user1347525 Different systems encode line breaks differently. If you are trying to read a file that was produced on Windows with a program running on your mac or linux computer, you may get extra lines that are not there in the file.

Comment: I am getting your point but I have used this code for reading from a number of file in same project but somehow it is giving me errors in this particular file only for others it just runs fine.

Comment: @user1347525 It is a problem with that one file then. Your code is good, just open the file in an editor, and fix the line breaks, or copy-paste its content line by line into a new file to make it work.

Comment: I debugged it again and strangely after every line it reads a blank line hence the code is not running forward. I used what @trutheality suggested and it is running now but still I am still unsure of this strange behavior of this file.

Comment: @user1347525 It's not strange at all: your file must have been created on windows, so `\n\r` is used as the line separator instead of just `\n`. Java gets confused, and returns an empty line for the second one. Open the file in an editor, join all lines in one, and then put line breaks back manually, that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong indicies for you matrix, I think it should be something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while((input=br.readLine())!= null) {               
    String [] temp=input.split(",");
    //System.out.println(input.split(",").length);
    covar[i][0]= new Double(temp[0]);
    covar[i][1]=new Double(temp[1]);
    covar[i][2]=new Double(temp[2]);
    covar[i][3]=new Double(temp[3]);
    covar[i][4]=new Double(temp[4]);
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file might have some strange line-terminators that are making the reader think there is an extra line.

You can try to just make your code skip blank lines:

```
while((input=br.readLine())!= null) {
    if( input.length() > 0 ){
        String [] temp=input.split(",");
        for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
            covar[j][i] = new Double(temp[i]);
        }
    }
    ++j;
}
```